# Adding/cloning project to/from git repo by ssh on Linux

Tags: linux, git, ssh, clone, commit

Locally I have created a repo with my some file. Then I would like to add this repo (this file) to the repo which is on other server by ssh (on Linux). So on my local machine:

```
mkdir localRepo && cd /localRepo
git init
touch someFile
git add .
git commit -m "add someFile"
git remote add origin ssh://smith@sam.uf.com/srv/git/hello.git
```

To check if everyhing go well on local machine I have created a new repo and clone from other machine:

```
cd .. && mkdir localRepo2 && cd localRepo2
git init
git clone ssh://smith@sam.uf.com/srv/git/hello.git
```

In the repo in "localRepo2" on local machine there is no file "someFile", but it should be. What I have done wrong?

Comment: Maybe `push` after add remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git remote add origin ssh://smith@sam.uf.com/srv/git/hello.git
```

only adds a reference to the remote in your local repo. It doesn't push / get any file.

From your `localRepo` you should push your file to your remote repo

```
git push origin master
```

Then to get it from another local repo you could either clone a new local repo now, or go to the `localRepo2` and do

```
git pull origin master
```